# Class is not defined onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I use the new class syntax for JS. When I press a button, I want to call a method from a class. To archieve this, I set this method static.

```
class NoteController { // The controller class
    constructor() { // Initialization
        // ...
    }

    static CreateNote() { // The method to call - static
        // ....
    }
}




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    // ....
    <script src="NoteController.js"></script> // Link the js file to the html file

</head>

<body>

    // ....
    <button type="button" id="btnCreateNote" onclick="NoteController.CreateNote()">Create</button> // call the method

</body>

</html>
```

When I click the button, it says, NoteController is not defined. I really do not get, what is wrong there.

A picture of my project folder:

[image]

Maybe this helps.

Comment: Is NoteController.js in the same folder were your HTML page is? What exact error are you getting? I'll bet my money on the file not being loaded on the HTML page.

Comment: I just updated my post with a picture :)

Comment: Added a response and a working example. not separated on a file as in your structure but I hope it helps to understand what is missing in your working code.

Comment: Peter, did the solution I posted worked for you? If so could you please flag as the response? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: 
Correction to make it static:

```
<script>
class NoteController { // The controller class
    constructor() { // Initialization
        // ...
        alert('constructor called');
    }

    static CreateNote() { // The method to call - static
        // ....
        alert('create note');
    }
}
//var nc=new NoteController();
//console.log(nc);
</script>


<button type="button" id="btnCreateNote" onclick="NoteController.CreateNote()">Create</button> // call the method
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o47jq2L4/2/)

This is the working example of your code:

```
<script>
class NoteController { // The controller class
    constructor() { // Initialization
        // ...
        alert('constructor called');
    }

    CreateNote() { // The method to call - static
        // ....
        alert('create note');
    }
}
var nc=new NoteController();
console.log(nc);
</script>


<button type="button" id="btnCreateNote" onclick="nc.CreateNote()">Create</button> // call the method
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o47jq2L4/1/)

Comment: The method should be static, called without an instance of the NoteController.

Comment: My bad, added a new example with static method.

Comment: I was testing the same thing, but if you move the JS code to the JS area in jsfiddle, it stops working, not sure why. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69b06hvj)

Comment: If you use this syntax, even if it is on a different file, it works fine, test it locally.    (take a look at the change in the JAVASCRIPT settings) https://jsfiddle.net/69b06hvj/3/

Comment: Ha, scope issues. Jsfiddle is (by default) wrapping the JS tab in an `onload` function. By setting the 'no-wrap' load type it works. So the OP issue must be regarding how the js file is being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Since lack of information about NoteController.js,I assume that your NoteController.js has below code.

```
    function NoteController()
    {
    //variables
    //sub functions
   function CreateNote()
     {
      //code
     }
    }
```

So now you need to create the object of the function and call it.

```
<script src="NoteController.js"></script>
<script>
var _noteController=new NoteController();
</script>

<body>
    <button type="button" id="btnCreateNote" 
onclick="_noteController.CreateNote()">Create</button> 
</body>
```

Comment: No no, as you can see above, this is a full class :) It is a relatively new syntax

Comment: Just inspect the button element and check what is bind for onclick?And also how the NoteController is defined on the html rendered page.

Answer (score 1):

Include your class inside the `<script>` tags, So that the browser will identify the javascript code and execute it!